# Emacs got blue background after upgrading to 3.20

Tags: arch-linux, emacs, gnome3

OS: Archlinux

Emacs: 24.5

Theme: Solarized-light

It is ok before upgrading to `gnome-unstable(3.20)`

[image: ugly bg]

Comment: Do you get the same result with `-q`? And you might find Emacs Stack Exchange a better place to ask this.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes!

Comment: @FaheemMitha I think this issue relates to gnome, not emacs only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug seems to be in the gnome-unstable gtk3 package. As a temporary workaround you could disable the gnome-unstable repository in your pacman.conf and downgrade your local gnome packages to the stable versions with

```
sudo pacman -Syyuu
```

In my case this fixed the blue screen bug in emacs.

Comment: Hope the stable gnome 3.20 release would resolve this

Comment: The recent gnome update have fixed this issue